# Minipages images location problem

Tags: graphics, minipage

I'm a n00b with LaTeX and I'm having some trouble with the minipages command. The pictures in this example end up floating overtop of the caption at the bottom for some reason.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[dvips]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvips,final]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
   \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{picture1.eps}
   \end{minipage}
\hfill
   \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{picture2.eps}
   \end{minipage}
   \caption{BLABLABLABLABLABLABL BALBLABLABLABLALBALBALBLABLBLABLABLABLABLABLBALABLBALBALBAL.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Also of note is that it works correctly on one machine, but incorrectly on another. I've tried reinstalling MiKTeX on the machine that doesn't work but had some trouble with the uninstall process. Any help with how to fix minipages or MiKTeX would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: (1) Can we see those images? (2) does the images have the correct size? Some EPS have bad bounding boxes. what happens if you use `\fbox{\includegr.....{image}}`? BTW: you do not need the `dvips` option for either of those packages, it can detect that themselfs.

Comment: The minipages are doing nothing useful there you could replace `begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{picture1.eps}
   \end{minipage}` by `\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{picture1.eps}`  It's usually best to miss of the `.eps` so that pdflatex loads a pdf file and latex loads an eps file. (most likely you are using pdflatex on one of the machines)

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I solved the problem by using an older version of the MikTeX installer on the machine that wasn't working (basic-miktex-2.9.4813-x64.exe instead of 2.9.5105-x64).

Comment: The \fbox works correctly and I also tried without using the minipages and it works correctly as well. What's the purpose of minipages, then? I guess if you have text and images that you want to put beside eachother it would be necessary.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was a localized issue solved by reinstalling the TeX distribution.